# Prove if sum of $3$ numbers $\geq 3$ then at least one them must be $\geq 1$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

I am helping out a friend who can't seem to get these proofs; unfortunately, I can't find them either.  Can someone tell me how to solve this or point me in the right direction with resources?

Question 1:

> Prove that for all real numbers x, y, and z, if x + y + z greater than or equal 
>        to 3, then either x greater than or equal to 1 or y greater than or equal to 1 
>        or z greater than or equal to 1.

$$\forall x,y,z\in \mathbb R, \quad x+y+z \geq 3 \implies x \geq 1 \lor y \geq 1 \lor z\geq1 $$

Question 2:

> Prove that for all real numbers x and y, if xy less than or equal to 2, then 
>       either x less than or equal to square root of 2 or y less than or equal to 
>       square root of 2.

$$\forall x,y \in \mathbb R,\quad xy \leq 2 \implies x \leq \sqrt 2 \lor y \leq \sqrt 2$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are three ways you can choose to prove conditionals (if-then statements). There are other ways but these are most common.

**Direct Proof**

If $A$, then $B$.

$(A \implies B)$

Assume $A$ is true, then show that when $A$ is true that $B$ must also be true. This seems like it should be the simplest way, but that is not always the case.

**Contrapositive**

If not $B$, then not $A$.

$(\neg B \implies \neg A)$

This is when you assume that $B$ is false, then show that when $B$ is false then $A$ must also be false. This works because $(\neg B \implies \neg A)$ is logically equivalent to $(A \implies B)$.

**Contradiction**

$A$ and not $B$.

$(A \land \neg B)$

This is when you assume that $A$ is true *and* that $B$ is false. Then go on with attempting to prove that assumption just to arrive at a contradiction, or an absurdity in the proof. By showing $(A \land \neg B)$ is a contradiction you have done enough to prove that $(A \implies B)$ so you can end your proof there.

I know this is all formal symbolic logic but it's quite useful in math proofs. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Proof 1.

By contradiction, x<1 and y<1 and z<1 implies x+y+z <3, so this assumption is false. Thus we have x>=1 or y>=1 or z>=1.

Proof 2 can be done in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks @ZhiyongWang.  I'll try to do #2 and post my response here.

Comment: I have a feeling I have it wrong but here it is: IF X <2 and y <2 then that implies that xy greater than or equal to 2.  Thus we have xy greater than or equal to 2?

Comment: @AAA That's not right. If $x<2$ and $y<2$ how do you get $xy\ge 2$? I edited my answer with a possible reasoning you can use, which is the one both me and Zhiyong have in mind.

Answer (score 3):

$$(A\Rightarrow B) \equiv (\lnot B\Rightarrow\lnot A)$$

1. The statement is equivalent to its *contraposition*: if $x< 1$ *and* $y< 1$ *and* $z< 1$ then $x+y+z< 3$.
2. Similarly, use contraposition.

Comment: Thanks @Berci.  I'll try to do #2 and post my response here.

Comment: @GitGud: yes, absolutely right. Was too late..

Comment: @Berci Comment deleted.

Answer (score 2):

**Proof of part 1:** Let $M$ be the largest value of $x,y,z$ then at most there are 3 different values : $M,M-a,M-b$ where $a,b \geq 0$.

Now writing $x+y+z \geq 3$ in terms of $M$ 
we have 
$$M+(M-a)+(M-b) \geq 3$$

$$3M-a-b \geq 3$$
$$3M \geq 3 +a + b$$
$$M \geq 1 + \frac {a}{3} + \frac{b}{3} \implies M \geq 1 $$ Since $a,b \geq 0 \implies \frac {a}{3} + \frac{b}{3}\geq0$
Since M was the maximum of $x,y,z$ then at least one of them $\geq 1 $
$$\square1$$

**Proof of part 2:**
For part 2 we have :
Let $M$ be the lowest value of $x,y$ then at most there are 2 different values $M,M\alpha$ where $\alpha \geq 1$

Now writing $xy \leq 2$ in terms of $M$
we have 
$$M(M\alpha)\leq 2$$
$$M^2\alpha\leq 2$$
$$M\leq \sqrt \frac{2}{\alpha}$$
But since $\alpha \geq 1 \implies \frac{2}{\alpha} \leq 2$ we have
$$M \leq \sqrt \frac{2}{\alpha}\leq \sqrt 2$$
or just 
$$M \leq \sqrt 2 $$ 
$$\square 2$$